# Internet Explorer "Microsoft recommended settings" tab keeps popping up

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1.

Since a month or two (I don't know the exact timing), every now and then when I start the browser an additional tab automatically opens:

[image: ab]

(The actual language is Italian, just like the system language; I've manually changed the link from `it-it` to `en-us` to display the english language version for clarity).

The browser home page is set to Google (and only that one), the new tab settings are configured to display the home page when opening a new tab. And yet, this page keeps randomly popping up.

This doesn't always happen; the tab opens at random times, and only when starting up the browser; it never happens when actually opening a new tab in a running browser. But sometimes, when the browser is started, this additional tab is displayed after the actual home page.

If I close it, it goes away and doesn't appear again for a while; but sooner or later it pops up again; the interval seems to be several days, but it's not fixed.

**This strange behaviour only started several weeks ago**; I don't know exactly when (the system has been in use for years). But If I had to guess, I'd say this stated after an update, which apparently introduced a bug. But I can't find any mention of it anywhere.

Why is this page randomly displayed? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Same here on some Win7. Even though we have set the reg key DisableFirstRunCustomize and have been running for a long time. Additionally the IE hangs at the start (~60s) because the PCs have no internet connection via the firewall.